# Spring Security - Session Timeout without extending/renewing

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, session-timeout

Is there a way in Spring Security to set sessions to expire after a time, regardless of activity?

i.e. when someone logs in, they have exactly 30 minutes to work and then the session is dead, regardless of whether they have been navigating, making REST calls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. But you can use Quartz scheduler for job scheduling and execute a job when you need, for example 30 minutes after the user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below lines in your `web.xml` should work out ideally.

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```